# Scala private function

Tags: scala

I came across a code snippet in Scala that looked like this:

```
final class Test private (fn: Int => Int) {
  def square(i: Int) = i * i
 }

 object Test {
   def apply(fn: Int => Int) = new Test(fn)
 }
```

What would that mean? I could not find any references to this in the text materials that I have on Scala.

Edit: Found what I wanted in this link:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch04s05.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means `Test` class has a private constructor. It probably has factory methods in its companion object.

Comment: So is the fn: Int => Int is sort of redundant? What would it tell to the external world? Why would I need that?

Comment: No it's not redundant. Perhaps factory methods are building functions from other stuff and initializing the class with them. We're just guessing here until you paste the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, there are factory methods in the companion object. One of the apply method implements this function

Answer (score 3):

This means that the constructor is `private`.

The arguments in the class declaration are used to denote the constructor arguments.

To create such an object the companion object with factory methods can be used.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword **private** does not apply to the class, but to its constructor. It means that you can use the class anywhere, but cannot create it using its constructor. However, you can create it using the companion object, via *apply* (or any other method).

The thing is, *apply* has a special sugar: **()**.

It means that you can construct an instance just like you do with a case class:

```
val t = new Test(f) // won't work
val t = Test.apply(f) // works
val t = Test(f)
```

Comment: This answer is kind of misleading, as `apply` is not restricted to return a new instance, but rather is just a specially named method to treat the object on which it is called as if it were a function, hence the syntactic sugar `()`. On the other hand, creating a new instance is not limited to the companion object's `apply` method but new objects can only be created within the whole body of either the class `Test` or its companion object.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a class as final means you cannot `override` Test class.

And Test class has private constructor. So it can be used with in the class i.e `Test`